# Running script on Meterpreter in Msfconsole

Tags: ruby, unix, exploit, payload

The purpose of my task is to run a Ruby script, which executes key-logger exe file, and starts working on remote computer. I manage to successfully connect by apache2 server (i.e. my other VM enters a link in the browser and meterpreter starts to work) with `PAYLOAD php/meterpreter/reverse_tcp`. So when meterpreter starts to work , Im trying to run script: `run ruby.rb`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVEDI.jpg

---

**ruby.rb (with content)**

```
exec("/root/Desktop/time/time/bin/Debug/time.exe")
```

---

However, error is occurring and I dont understand **why**? **When I try to execute my time.exe file in WINDOWS it works perfectly**. The keylogger is written in c# if someone interested in looking at the code: https://ufile.io/y9n3z

Maybe someone can give my an advice or a workaround?

Comment: Is the Ruby script present at root/Desktop/ruby.rb? Since meterpreter cannot find the file at the specified location.

Comment: You could directly upload the keylogger exe to the system using the `upload` command. Also meterpreter has inbuilt options of keylogging. You can use `keyscan_start` command to start keylogger in meterpreter directly.